# Share image Whatsapp without confirming dispatch

Tags: image, send, whatsapp, caption

I want to send with my app image through Whatsapp.
I used this code , but after selecting the contact, I would avoid click on the "Sent" in the box where it asks you to enter the caption , I wish I could skip this step, you can in some way?

```
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();   
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");      
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedImageUri);
            sendIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Thanks in advance.